# Why doesn't lambda function accept parameter in bond with sorted()

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

```
Students = (("Squidward", "F", 60),
            ("Sandy", "A", 33),
            ("Patrick","D", 36),
            ("Spongebob","B", 20),
            ("Mr.Krabs","C", 78))

sort_grades = lambda grades: grades[1]

Sorted_Students = sorted(Students,key=sort_grades)
```

lambda function kinda has a **parameter grades**. Why don't we pass any parameters in Sorted_Students as a **key=** so **there is no parenthesis** after **sort_grades**. And this code somehow works even without passing any parameters as "grades" so we don't even run the lambda function (how without parameters - imposible). Please detail how this code works the most explicitly, so my dumb brain could get something from your comment

Comment: this might help: https://realpython.com/python-lambda/

Comment: IIUC, your question has more to do with the `key` than `lambda`. In any case, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) might help

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted states: " key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example, key=str.lower). The default value is None (compare the elements directly)."

Comment: So, in short, `sorted` calls the function specified by `key=` on each item to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` parameter of `sorted` is a function which will be applied to the elements in order to compare them to each other.
Therefore, we only pass the function itself without calling it.

I suggest you read the documentation first next time :)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 0):

To complete [Tomer Ariel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72304452/11563040), functions in python might be passed as argument just as any object. An other function from the python standard library that uses this feature is [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). This function take an iterable and a function, and return a generator of the result of the function applied to each element of the iterable. A way it could be implemented :

```
def map(iterable, f): # Note : f is a function!
    return (f(i) for i in iterable) # and is indeed called
```

And could be use this way :

```
print(list(map([1,2,3,4,5], lambda x: x*x))) #we convert the generator to a list so it displays nicely
#it prints in the shell : [1,4,9,16,25]
```